# Bootstrap 4.2.1 - Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'javascript:void(0);' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project which I started building on **bootstrap 4.0.0**. During this project, I had updated bootstrap regulary whenever the new versions ( 4.1.0  , 4.1.3 ) of bootstrap came and all the things were working perfectly until I have update to **bootstrap 4.2.1** from there I encountered error in console when ever I click on the document

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on
>   'Document': 'javascript:void(0);' is not a valid selector.

I figured out that it occur due to the dropdown because of this error the dropdown does not work. I also checked, that if I am using **href="javascript:void(0);"**, **href="#!"** the error occur but if i use anchor tag without href or href="#" then it is working fine.

**Note:-** I need the solution with **href="javascript:void(0);** as **href="#** in the address link does not look pretty and page scrolls up to the top

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void();" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wReoxa)

Comment: If it's a fake anchor anyway, why use `<a>`? You can just use `<button>`.

Comment: @fen1x    The project is about to be finished and we cannot afford to go back or change any element as the project consist of more than 100 pages and it was working fine till bootstrap 4.1.3.

Comment: This is a bug in Bootstrap 4.2.1 and will be fixed in 4.3.0: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903

Comment: As mentioned in the bug ticket there's a workaround... https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903#issuecomment-450292043

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution that works for me

Snippet from Bootstrap 4.1.3

```
getSelectorFromElement: function getSelectorFromElement(element) {
    var selector = element.getAttribute('data-target');

    if (!selector || selector === '#') {
      selector = element.getAttribute('href') || '';
    }

    try {
      return document.querySelector(selector) ? selector : null;
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
},
```

Replace it from Bootstrap 4.2.1

```
getSelectorFromElement: function getSelectorFromElement(element) {
  var selector = element.getAttribute('data-target');

  if (!selector || selector === '#') {
    var hrefAttr = element.getAttribute('href');
    selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr !== '#' ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
  }

  return selector && document.querySelector(selector) ? selector : null;
},
```

Thanks to PixemWeb github solution

For more info here is the link https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903#issuecomment-449600715

Answer (score 6):

I was having this issue, and a comment on this [reported issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903) clued me into the solution. I was copying the example from the Bootstrap docs, and I had to remove the ID from the parent link, and instead have that ID on the container for the child links, without the aria-labeledby property, and add a reference in the parent link data-target property.

This example shows what I was doing, which caused the console errors:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/Summary/Commercial" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navToggleCommercial" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Commercial
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navToggleCommercial">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Summary/Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/Summary/Commercial" data-target="#navToggleCommercial" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Individual
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="navToggleCommercial">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Summary/Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: This is a bug in Bootstrap 4.2.1 and will be fixed in 4.3.0: github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903

Comment: This has not even fixed in 5.0 ver.

Answer (score 5):

=== Change in bootstrap.js v4.2.1 ===

Find below block

```
getSelectorFromElement: function getSelectorFromElement(element) {
  var selector = element.getAttribute('data-target');

  if (!selector || selector === '#') {
    var hrefAttr = element.getAttribute('href');
    selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr !== '#' ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
  }

  return selector && document.querySelector(selector) ? selector : null;
},
```

Need to add try and catch exception only as below

Replace

```
return selector && document.querySelector(selector) ? selector : null;
```

with

```
try {
    return selector && document.querySelector(selector) ? selector : null;
} catch (err) {
    return null;
}
```

=== Change in bootstrap.min.js v4.2.1 ===

Replace

```
return e&&document.querySelector(e)?e:null
```

with

```
try{return e&&document.querySelector(e)?e:null}catch(err){return null;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getSelectorFromElement: function getSelectorFromElement(element) {
            var selector = element.getAttribute('data-target');
            if (!selector || selector === '#') {
                var hrefAttr = element.getAttribute('href');

                //selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr !== '#' ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
                selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr.indexOf('#') === 0 ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
            }

            return (selector && document.querySelector(selector)) ? selector : null;
        }
```

this function through error due to document.querySelector not find id like "#home" so if any string not contain # prefix it through error.
so replace this:

```
selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr !== '#' ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
```

from this

```
selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr.indexOf('#') === 0 ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
```

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works on Bootstrap 4.3. Bootstrap does'n count with links in .dropdown-toggle other than #, which is understandable but it bit cripples the menu while we  wanna go beyond its native behavior.  Change it in the /js/src/util/index.js before you commit "npm run dist".

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion:

Remove the empty `href` attribute & add `cursor:pointer` style to make A element clickable.

```css
#dropdownMenuLink {
  cursor: pointer; /* not necessary for Bootstrap */
  color: white /* change if you want */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ziFidFTgxJXHMDttyPJKDuTlmxJlwbSkojudK/CkRqKDOmeSbN6KLrGdrBQnT2n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

as others said in comments

> This is a bug in Bootstrap 4.2.1 and will be fixed in 4.3.0:
>   github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903

just need to user 4.3.0 of bootstrap

just replace this

```
 <script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a9xOd0rz8w0J8zqj1qJic7GPFfyMfoiuDjC9rqXlVOcGO/dmRqzMn34gZYDTel8k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

with this

```
<script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a9xOd0rz8w0J8zqj1qJic7GPFfyMfoiuDjC9rqXlVOcGO/dmRqzMn34gZYDTel8k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: no such version.. its a custom BOOTSTRAP library that fixes some RTL issuses..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the anchor of the dropdown menu item is `#` instead of a path.

Solution:
I use to Link instead of an `a` in `React` and replace it with simple `<a href="#" ...` and it is working now.