# How to fix this Jquery bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6 Bug that occurs in the navigation bar?

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask

I am using Flask- Bootstrap to create my website and I am very new to it. 
I am experiencing the following bug from the following file:

```
<script 
src="/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
</script>
```

When I add a link to my navigation bar like below

```
<a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ url_for('team') }}">Team</a>
```

I get the following error in Chrome's developer console and the file does not work:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '/upload' is not a valid selector.
    at Object.getSelectorFromElement (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1377)
    at http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:67292
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at n.t.refresh (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:67266)
    at new n (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:66907)
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:69792)
    at Function.each (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:2573)
    at w.fn.init.each (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:1240)
    at w.fn.init.n._jQueryInterface [as scrollspy] (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:69744)
    at http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/js/agency.min.js:7:462
```

But when I add no link to the navigation bar, the js file works as expected.

How can I overcome this bug, please?

Many Thanks,

Ishack

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Bootstrap v4.2.1, this could be a bug which is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921939/bootstrap-4-2-1-failed-to-execute-queryselector-on-document-javascriptv) and also this [github thread](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903).

Until 4.3.0 is released, a temporary workaround might be to go back to an earlier version of bootstrap, which shouldn't effect you massively if you're just building your first site.

Here are the CDN links for 4.1.3:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3

Or as a quick fix test, just swap the script tag with:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-E/V4cWE4qvAeO5MOhjtGtqDzPndRO1LBk8lJ/PR7CA4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry, none of those solutions work, unfortunately. Do you have any other solutions, please?

Comment: It would be very helpful if this code was on github (can you do that?) then I could see the whole lot to help further.

Comment: yeah sure, I could do it on CodePen, is that ok?

Comment: Either or, github's quite good cause it lets others clone the repo to run it locally was my thinking, and also supports its own issue threads.  Code pen's fine for some samples though.

Comment: Hi, this whole code at Github: https://github.com/ishackm/Code-Bank/blob/master/jquery%20Bootstrap. Please have a look many thanks, Moshi

Comment: Thanks, I'll spin up an issue on that repo as comments here aren't meant for extended discussion :)